# Android- Error When using putExtra(String name, String value) method

Tags: java, android

i have to activities, the first activity contains an EditText & a button, when i press the button the value entered in the EditText field should be transferred to a TextView in the other activity,
but when i run the app, enter some text & click the button, the app crashes & the emulator shows an error, i tried a lot of things, but didn't know what's the problem

FIRST ACTIVITY CODE:

```
 package com.example.sqa;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.*;
   public class TheFirst extends Activity {


TextView tv1;
     EditText ed1;
     Button b1;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_first);
        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final Intent i1=new Intent(TheFirst.this,TheSecond.class);
        String temp=ed1.getText().toString();
        i1.putExtra("v1", temp);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(i1);

            }
        });

     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.the_first, menu);
        return true;
     }

  }
```

SECONDE ACTIVITY CODE:

```
   package com.example.sqa;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.view.Menu; 
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class TheSecond extends Activity {


    TextView tv2;
    Button b2;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_second);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        Intent i2=getIntent();
        tv2.setText(i2.getStringExtra("v1"));

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i1=new Intent(TheSecond.this,TheFirst.class);
                startActivity(i1);

            }
            });
    }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.the_second, menu);
        return true;
     }

    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml FILE:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.sqa"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

     <application
         android:allowBackup="true"
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



         <activity
            android:name="com.example.sqa.TheFirst"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>



         <activity
             android:name="com.example.sqa.TheSecond"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_the_second" >
         </activity>


     </application>

    </manifest>
```

LOGCAT:

```
   04-10 19:12:31.070: D/dalvikvm(1714): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 5% free 3279K/3440K, paused 45ms, total 48ms
   04-10 19:12:31.130: D/gralloc_goldfish(1714): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
   04-10 19:12:37.530: D/AndroidRuntime(1714): Shutting down VM
   04-10 19:12:37.530: W/dalvikvm(1714): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1afdb90)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): Process: com.example.sqa, PID: 1714
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqa/com.example.sqa.TheSecond}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at com.example.sqa.TheSecond.onCreate(TheSecond.java:26)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
   04-10 19:12:37.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1714):  ... 11 more
   04-10 19:13:03.340: I/Process(1714): Sending signal. PID: 1714 SIG: 9
```

activity_the_first.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TheFirst" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/s2" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/s3" />


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/s1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_the_second.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TheSecond" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/s4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:text="@string/s3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please let me know what Exception you are getting. so i can help you.

Comment: @Djhseen `Button` `button1` is in `activity_the_first.xml` or `activity_the_second.xml`

Comment: @Djhseen What is line nnmber 26 in `TheSecond.java`?

Comment: @Djhseen also post your `activity_the_second.xml` layout

Comment: @ Hariharan tv2.setText(i2.getStringExtra("v1"));

Answer (score 4):

First Move this

```
 String temp=ed1.getText().toString();
```

Inside your Button `onclick()` event like:

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String temp=ed1.getText().toString();
            i1.putExtra("v1", temp);
            startActivity(i1);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the below is correct?

```
b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

R.id.button1 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity replace this line.
    tv2.setText(i2.getStringExtra("v1"));
to 
    String text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("vi");
    tv2.setText(text);

Answer (score 0):

make sure textView2 is presnet in activity_the_second.xml

Answer (score 0):

Well i think everything is clear now, 
conflicting IDs
i didn't pay attention for that because i use Eclipse & i don't mess with default IDs usually,
& this is the first time i deal with multi-activities, so it seems like eclipse give different IDs to object in one layout, & once i create another activity layout it gives the same IDs again, although both layouts are in the same project.
Thank You All Guys.